# CBP fine receipt

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, fines

I got fined by U.S. Customs & Border Protection in 2012 for bringing food (I filled in the paper that I did not bring any food when I arrived at the airport). The fine was about 300 dollars, and I paid the fine right there. However, I do not think I have the receipt, and I am filling some paperwork that needs that receipt.

Should I contact CBP to get a new receipt? Would they still have my record?

Comment: I think you have the wrong agency, for starters.  TSA only handles screening passengers before boarding flights.  Issues of what is allowed to be imported into the country would be handled by CBP.

Comment: CBP have always been quick at getting back to me here: https://help.cbp.gov/app/ask

Comment: Please add more details. How did you pay the fine?Did you use credit card, get any email of payment? If you paid cash and misplaced a paper receipt there's not much you can do except call them and ask

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks! I will contact CBP. I  probably forgot what happened.

Comment: @CJH: I paid by my credit card, but I no longer use that bank. I tried to call, but I could not reach anyone in person.

Comment: @SamJones: How long does it take them? Thanks

Comment: Hmm...if you are able to get the printout of the credit card transaction maybe that could work? Really depends on who's looking at it and if they need official receipt. You have credit card statements from that time?

Comment: @manman123 it says up to 10 days i think but usually its the same day, they'll point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

While it is not clear why you would need this, [Customs and Border Patrol own requirements](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/588/~/requirements-for-keeping-cbp-records-and-entry-documents-on-file) for how long you, and it, needs to retain such a record is 5 years. While your receipt may no longer be in CBP records, you could still make a Freedom of Information Request, just in case.

> **Requirements for keeping CBP records and entry documents on file**
>
> **How long are importers, carriers, exporters, travelers and brokers required to keep U.S. Customs and Border Protection records and entry documents on file?**
>
> Importers, exporters, carriers, and brokers are required to keep their U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP) records and entry documents for five years from date of entry, or five years from the date of the activity that required the maintenance of the records. However, travelers who physically clear CBP by making an oral declaration are not required to maintain supporting documents, as long as they are not declaring commercial merchandise.
>
> For additional information on the requirements for maintaining CBP records, please refer to [19 CFR § 163.4](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=b609ff897193beb3defecda5c3e63aab&ty=HTML&h=L&mc=true&n=pt19.2.163&r=PART).
>
> **[What Records can CBP Provide under FOIA?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1553/related/1)**
>
> [Records Regarding My Inspection or Examination upon My Arrival at a U.S. Port of Entry](https://foiaonline.regulations.gov/foia/action/public/request/publicPreCreate)
>
> Concerns about how you were treated by CBP officers, or if you have a general or specific question(s) about CBP or your CBP inspection:
>
> [CBP Info Center](https://help.cbp.gov/)
>   or call (877) CBP-5511 (227-5511) for U.S. Callers or (202) 325-8000 for International callers